# Magento2 disabled product quantity text field to product edit page at admin panel

Tags: magento2

How can we disable quantity text fields of product edit form at admin side or how can we make it ready only?

We found that it's already disabled with bundle product but we want to do this with all type of products.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you will have to code this on your own

Comment: Thank you @Philipp Sander, any suggestion for this code?

Comment: do you just want the qty field to be disabled in the backend or do you also wan't to restrict API or anything else?

Comment: Just want to disabled in the backed. Just want to make it read-only from product edit page, nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create catalog_product_new.xml file under your_module/view/adminhtml/layout

Below is content of catalog_product_new.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="js">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="js.seller_stock_disabler" template="Rootways_CatalogInventory::product/stock/disabler.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 2: Create disabler.phtml file under your_module/view/adminthml/templates/product/stock

Below is content of disabler.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($) {
    window.afterOptionsInit = function() {
        if (!jQuery('[data-index = quantity_and_stock_status_qty] input')[0]) {
            setTimeout(function(){window.afterOptionsInit();}, 500);
            return;
        }
        $( "[data-index = quantity_and_stock_status_qty] input" ).attr("disabled", "true");
        $( "[data-index = quantity_and_stock_status_qty] .admin__field-group-additional" ).hide();
    }
    window.afterOptionsInit();
});
</script>
```